# Extracting edge weights with Subgraph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, properties

I am trying to efficiently extract sub-graphs from very large weighted directed graphs.  I thought [`Subgraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subgraph.html) would do this, but it does not, which seems a bit odd since edge weights are intrinsic properties of the graph.

First, a toy directed, weighted graph as an example:

```
size = 10;
rAm = Table[If[Or[i  == j, RandomReal[{0, 1}] < .8], Infinity, 
         RandomInteger[{1, 100}] - 1], {i, size}, {j, size}];
wAg = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[rAm]
```

[image]

Extracting the weighted adjacency matrix

```
MatrixForm[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[wAg]
```

[image]

But when I extract a subgraph that includes the first 6 vertices, the edge weights are not preserved.

```
rSg = Subgraph[wAg, Range[6]]
WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[rSg] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

I would expect:

[image]

Edge weights do not come with the `Subgraph` even if I specify edges, as opposed to vertices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Potential solution could be:

```
Clear[exWtSuGr];
exWtSuGr[gr_, verts_] := Module[{sg, el, ew, wAg}, {
    sg = Subgraph[gr, verts];
    el = EdgeList[sg];
    ew = PropertyValue[{gr, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ el;
    wAg = Graph[verts, el, EdgeWeight -> ew]
    }[[1]]]

GR1 = exWtSuGr[wAg, Range[6]]
WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[GR1] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use [`WeightedAdjacencyGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedAdjacencyGraph) on the relevant part of the weighted adjacency matrix? The only issue with this approach is that [`WeightedAdjacencyGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedAdjacencyGraph) expects [`Infinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infinity) for missing edges instead of `0`. The following function accounts for this:

```
subgraph[g_, v_] := WeightedAdjacencyGraph @ fixBackground @ WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g][[v, v]]
fixBackground[sa_SparseArray] := Replace[
    sa,
    Verbatim[SparseArray][a_, b_, _, c__] :> SparseArray[a, b, Infinity, c]
]
```

Using a version of your example:

```
SeedRandom[0];
size=10;
rAm=Table[If[Or[i==j,RandomReal[{0,1}]<.8],Infinity,RandomInteger[{1,100}]-1],{i,size},{j,size}];
wAg=WeightedAdjacencyGraph[rAm]
```

[image]

we get (note the correct adjacency matrix):

```
subgraph[wAg, {1,3,5,7,9}]
WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[%] //MatrixForm //TeXForm
```

[image]

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 14 \\
>  95 & 97 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 25 & 0 & 76 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

The graph looks the same as what is returned by [`Subgraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subgraph):

[image]

Comment: This is basically what I do (and what I almost posted earlier today). `IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph` from IGraph/M can use any element to indicate a non-existent connection, so adding `Infinity` wouldn't be necessary. Some minor problems with your implementation: 1. the null graph has no adjacency matrix and therefore needs special handling.  2. directedness needs to be explicitly transferred, otherwise a directed graph that is identical to its reverse will get converted to undirected. 3. the vertex names may not be identical to the vertex indices; they may not even be integers.

Comment: I had [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/7HXie5Ei) when I decided not to post after all (because the performance gain wasn't significant enough, and if performance were the goal, other, much uglier solutions could help).

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe:

```
subGraphWeightLookup = 
 Association[Thread[EdgeList[wAg] -> 
 DeleteCases[
  Flatten[ReplacePart[Normal[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[wAg]], 
    Position[rAm, 0] -> -1]], 0]]] /. x_ /; x == -1 -> 0;
```

(*The -1 is a dummy variable allowing reinsertion of '0' elements.*)

```
Subgraph[wAg, Range[6], 
 EdgeWeight -> (subGraphWeightLookup[#] & /@ 
    EdgeList[Subgraph[wAg, Range[6]]])]

WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[%] // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 2):

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) now includes `IGWeightedSubgraph`, a function to extract subgraphs while preserving edge weights.  Unlike the adjacency matrix method, it also works with multigraphs.

---

This is reliable and marginally faster than the original solution by GraphMan.  It makes use of IGraph/M.

```
ClearAll[subgraph]
subgraph[g_?MultigraphQ, vs_List] := $Failed
subgraph[g_?MixedGraphQ, vs_List] := $Failed
subgraph[wg_?GraphQ, {}] := IGEmptyGraph[] (* also works around bug in M versions where Subgraph fails on empty graphs *)
subgraph[wg_?IGEdgeWeightedQ, vs_List] :=
    With[{ind = VertexIndex[wg, #] & /@ vs},
      IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[
       VertexList[wg][[ind]],
       WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[wg][[ind, ind]],
       DirectedEdges -> DirectedGraphQ[wg]
      ]
    ]
subgraph[g_?GraphQ, vs_List] := Subgraph[g, vs]
```